# Disabling layout for AJAX module

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

How can I disable the layout for AJAX module?
I have crated the module and tried to add the entry to view.yml referring to the module as ajax:, but it didn't work. 
Currently, I use $this->setLayout(false), which is not really nice...
Also, according [this](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/13-View) doc, view.yml is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to. XHR requests are automatically rendered without layout.

Comment: How does Symfony recognize it's XHR?

Comment: JavaScript libraries will add an extra HTTP request header 'X-REQUESTED-WITH: XMLHttpRequest' to any Ajax request.

Comment: How to let the layout be returned? Now I need it for my AJAX.

Comment: $this->setLayout('layout'); inside the action should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

About your question roman about how symfony recognize that it's a XHR. there is a function that you can use in symfony that tests the requests against that. It goes like the following

```
$request->isXmlHttpRequest()
```

this return true if the request came from an ajax call. very helpful function when making an action for ajax calls and when you want it to only respond to ajax calls.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I would not use it like that. Because, what else request could that be if it's AJAX API? IMHO, turning off main layout for the module is better way rather than having conditionals. Maybe isXmlHttpRequest() is designed for those who mix different types of requests in scope of one action?